# Laravel belongsTo returning null when using 'with'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm just getting started with Laravel so please forgive any noobness.

I have a `User` and `Order` model, a user has many orders:

```
# Inside User model
public function orders()
{
    $this->hasMany('Order');
} 

# Inside Order
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

// Not sure if this is upsetting anything (also in Order)
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
}
```

So I think I have the above right.

But when I do this:

```
 $users = User::with('orders')->find(1);
 return $users;
```

I get `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`.

However, if I do it the other way around, it works great:

```
$orders = Order::with('User')->get();
return $orders;
```

What am I doing wrong / what don't I understand?! Or is my problem bigger than I think?

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem is you don't have `return` for your `orders` relationship. It should be:

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany('Order');
}
```

You should also use your relationships case sensitive. you showed:

```
$orders = Order::with('User')->get();
```

is working, but you should rather use

```
$orders = Order::with('user')->get();
```

to avoid extra queries to your database in future

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that runs across this, I was having the same issue, but my problem was that I had the foreign/local keys swapped. Example:

```php
// This is correct for hasX relationships
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'user_id', 'local_key_user_id');
}

// This is correct for belongsTo relationships
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'local_key_user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Notice that for hasX relationships, the foreign key is the second parameter, and the local key is the third. However, for belongsTo relationships, these two are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't answer this particular question but it relates to the title. I had the same issue here is the wrong query

```
 $offer = Offer::with([
            'images:name,id,offer_id',
            'offer_options:offer_option,value,id,offer_id',
            'user:id,name,avatar'])
            ->select(['id', 'views', 'type', 'status'])
            ->where('id', $id)->get();
```

the model look like this

```
class Offer extends Model { 


function user(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

The User

```
class User extends ..... {

    function offer(): HasMany {
       return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
    }
}
```

The issue with the query is I was not selecting user_id, i.e in my `select` function `user_id` column was not included and that is why I was getting null for user

according to Laravel docs

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and
> any **relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to
> retrieve.**

So the correct query is

```
$offer = Offer::with([
                'images:name,id,offer_id',
                'offer_options:offer_option,value,id,offer_id',
                'user:id,name,avatar'])
                ->select(['id', 'views', 'type', 'status','user_id'])
                ->where('id', $id)->get();
```