# Method with does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Below is my code to get all users and role info for each user.**

```
$Users = \App\Models\User\User_Model::all()
        ->with("Role")->get();
return view("User.List", array("Users" => $Users));
```

**In my user model, A function is defined like below.**

```
public function Role()
{
    $this->hasOne("\App\Models\User\Role_Model", "RoleID");
}
```

**I am getting below error**

> Method with does not exist.

**Question ?**
Am I missing anything ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, [according to this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) you need to use `return $this->hasOne()` instead of `$this->hasOne()`. This does not fix your error, but will probably avoid the error you're going to get after fixing this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `all()` call (which internally does a `get()` to turn your query builder into a collection of results).

```
$Users = \App\Models\User\User_Model::with("Role")->get();
```

<sup>See also @h2ooooooo's comment that your `Role()` relationship should return the relationship.</sup>

Comment: @Helper That's because of the `Role()` not returning something. It needs to `return $this->hasOne(...)`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778082/laravel-belongsto-returning-null-when-using-with